# How to reduce vertical space between closing and signatur

Tags: moderncv

I'm using the `moderncv` package (`classic` style) and I would like to reduce the vertical space between the `\closing` of the letter and the signatur at the end.

[image]

The vertical space between **Sincerely** and **John Lennon** is too big.

Here my minimal working example:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.3 (29/10/16)

% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Damit Umlaute verwendet werden können
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.9cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John}  % Your first name
\familyname{Lennon} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{CV}
\address{\textifsymbol{18}  Champ Elisee}{12345, Dubai}
\mobile{+1234566789}
\email{email@email.com}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage

\recipient{Department of Mechatronics \rlap{and Robotics}}{Prof.\\YXCE 45\\987667 Baltimore} % Letter recipient
\date{Dubai, \today} % Letter date
\opening{} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely,} % Closing phrase

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\textbf{Letter of presentation}

\lipsum

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Using `\vspace` doesn't help and a solution like this one

```
\closing{Sincerely, \\ \textbf{John Lennon}}
```

works but produces my signature twice...so I have another problem...

Any idea?
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the relevant code you have to change in your preamble is the following (needed to add `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` for the usage of `@`):

```
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\[3em]% <===========================================
  {\bfseries\@firstname~\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfil%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}%
    \vfil}
```

The code `\\[3em]` defines the added space between your closing phrase and signature.

Change it to `\\` or change the value in `[]` to a value you like.

See the complete code

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% "ModernCV" CV and Cover Letter
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.3 (29/10/16)

% Original author:
% Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com) with modifications by:
% Vel (vel@latextemplates.com)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND OTHER DOCUMENT CONFIGURATIONS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % CV theme - options include: 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue} % CV color - options include: 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Damit Umlaute verwendet werden können
\usepackage{ifsym}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry} % Reduce document margins
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.9cm} % Uncomment to change the width of the dates column
%\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm} % For the 'classic' style, uncomment to adjust the width of the space allocated to your name
\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{
  \@closing\\% <===================================================
  {\bfseries\@firstname~\@lastname}%
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@enclosure}}{}{%
    \\%
    \vfil%
    {\color{color2}\itshape\enclname: \@enclosure}}%
    \vfil}
\makeatother


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND CONTACT INFORMATION SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\firstname{John}  % Your first name
\familyname{Lennon} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{CV}
\address{\textifsymbol{18}  Champ Elisee}{12345, Dubai}
\mobile{+1234566789}
\email{email@email.com}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   COVER LETTER
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\clearpage

\recipient{Department of Mechatronics \rlap{and Robotics}}{Prof.\\YXCE 45\\987667 Baltimore} % Letter recipient
\date{Dubai, \today} % Letter date
\opening{} % Opening greeting
\closing{Sincerely,} % Closing phrase

\makelettertitle % Print letter title

\textbf{Letter of presentation}

\lipsum

\makeletterclosing % Print letter signature

\newpage

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image]

Comment: It works!!! Many thanks... I found the code in the file: moderncvstyleclassic.sty

Comment: Can you please point me to right source where I can download the version 2.0.0? I tried this one: https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv?lang=de but the example files inside doesn't have any reference to 2.0.0

Comment: @dave That is the current version, as you can see on the first page comming up after clicking on your given link. Or you have a look into file `moderncv.cls` at the beginning ...